# VS 2013 - ASP.NET Web Application Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've tried to create new Web API project using "Visual C#/Web/ASP.NET Web Application" template, but i found that some templates and core references are missing:
[image]

.NET Framework 4.5 is selected

If I go to the "Visual C#/Web/Visual Studio 2012" I've got this:[image]

I know that I can create WebApi project by using MVC Template, but i don't know why some features are missing.
I have got VS2013 Ultimate edition (with update 2).

How can I obtain other features inside this template?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to the latest version

https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/details.aspx?id=44921

Comment: updated to version 4 - still no MVC and WebApi templates